# Performance difference between using OutputCache or cache API

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache

We have a page for which we create an HTML-string containing a full list of store information, which consumes a lot of CPU resources. To improve performance, we considered caching and found unexpectedly that there's a big difference between OutputCache and the Cache API.

We compared two ways: the first being using cache API to assign the string to a cache-key. The second way being creating a simple user control, and adding an  OutputCache directive inside the control. Since the OutputCache-directive in user control would also  work with server-side control.

We tested both cachings on our testwebsite and found that OutputCache used up 30% and Cache API used up only 15%. The only difference here were the different ways of caching: OutputCache or cache API. Can somebody explain the why there's such a big difference between these two caching methods?